# creating a onclick listview with three items KJV, WEB, BBE

Tags: android, listview

I have been having this problem in creating a list view activity in Android.

When you click on an item in the list view, it opens another activity. I want to have 3 list views which are KJV, BBE, WEB versions. I have already created the activities of the 3 versions already.

I tried it and it keep on crashing my ADT. Can anyone help?

I am also using the latest API which is API 19.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. It will help us to answer your question if you can edit your post to contain more information about your problem - what have you tried so far? Are you getting any errors when ADT crashes?

Comment: i was able to write the listview but i cannot make it clickabe to open a new activity